# Inject cookie into PhoneGap InAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

Is it possible to inject a cookie into a PhoneGap InAppBrowser window? Can I do it similar to the way you use `curl -c` to pass a cookie?

Comment: You can pass only url parameters. Have you any control in the destination url to transform this into a cookie?

Comment: Perhaps.  I'll look into using cURL to display the webpage with a cookie.